# Ionic plugin for Netbeans?

Tags: ionic-framework, netbeans

I'm looking for any way to work with Ionic Framework on Netbeans. I found a project in GitHub here: https://github.com/hexaviewtech/ionic-netbeans-plugin but I can't install it.

I'm following the how to install of the plugin here *Browse to the downloaded IonicExtention file and then click OK button* this file IonicExtension not exist.

How could I install IonicExtension for NetBeans ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only ways I can see for the file not exist is that you didn't download it or you downloaded it but saved it to a directory somewhere other than where you are looking.

Download from http://plugins.netbeans.org/download/plugin/3749

The file should be named:

```
1436530602_com-hexaview-ionicextension.nbm
```

It is most likely in your Downloads directory although that depends on your Browser and preferences.